# Is there a word for "couch-like"

Tags: single-word-requests

I wish to invoke laziness, lack of ambition, and lack of interest in life.  I do wish to avoid references to being fat, however.  I'm not trying to illustrate the corpulence of Jabba the Hut, but the slackness of the most-millennial in existence.

"Joseph reclined, couch-like, with glossy eyes, dirty hair, and no agenda whatsoever, for most of the day."

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'couch-like'? In what way is Joseph like a piece of furniture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good word for this is indolence

> indolence: disinclined to exert oneself; habitually lazy.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indolent)

Answer (score 1):

but if you're looking for something a bit more than 'lazy', or 'unmotivated', and have an audience with a post-high school vocabulary, you might try:

***complacent***

> complacent

[merriam-websters complacent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complacent)

> **complacent**:  marked by self-satisfaction especially when accompanied by unawareness of actual dangers or deficiencies :  marked by complacency :  self-satisfied

or

[merriam-websters complacency](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complacency)

> Definition of **complacency**,
>   (plural complacencies)
>
> 1
>   :  self-satisfaction especially when accompanied by unawareness of actual dangers or deficiencies
>
> *When it comes to safety, complacency can be dangerous*.
>
> 2
>   :  an instance of usually unaware or uninformed self-satisfaction

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reference to the word couch, I would recommend using the slang term [couch potato](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/couch+potato):

> person who spends much time sitting or lying down, usually watching television.

(link and defintion from The Free Dictionary)

The idiom evokes an image of a person who has rooted to a couch, growing there like a tuberous plant.

You would need to tweak your example slightly, perhaps, "Joseph had become a complete couch potato.  He spent most of the day reclined, with glossy eyes, dirty hair, and no agenda whatsoever."